# Jstree table definition

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jstree

I have integrated Jstree in my application, now i want to understand different column in that table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tree` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `position` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `left` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `right` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `level` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

This is the default table provided by the site.

Now if want to add a node, how do i know the value for left, right and level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a mix of `Adjacency list` an `nested sets`.

`Nested sets` are a better way of storing trees in a relational database.
It's hard to explain the principle you have to look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) and [here](http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2008/12/23/nested-set-in-mysql/).

When you use `nested sets` you don't need `parent_id`.
I think jstree provided a sample table where you can choose by yourself what technique you use.

Another way of storing trees in a database would be a [Closure Table](http://karwin.blogspot.de/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html).
It's my personal favourite. It's simple but powerful. But you hardly find anything about it on the net.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But really i dont want to restructure my table. Just i need to know about two columns left, right in the above table.

Comment: Have you read about nested sets? There you find an explanation about the columns left and right.